# Using Form Field Value to access an already existing variable

Tags: angular, typescript

Let's say I have multiple variables like this:

```
formGroup: FormGroup;
input = [
 {'key': value},
 {'key': value}
]
output = [
 {'key': value},
 {'key': value}
]
```

I also have `input` and `output` as options in a form field `dropdown` which gives the user the ability to change their value with just a click of a button.

When the user submits the form, the `onClick funtion` takes the form values and updates the fields. To do this, I did something like this

```
onSubmit(): void {
 this[this.formGroup.controls['controlName'].value].push(...)
}
```

```
constructor(formBuilder: FormBuilder){
 this.formGroup = formBuilder.group({
       controlName:''});
}
```

`this.formGroup.controls['controlName'].value` would have the value as `input` or `output`.
However, this results in an error

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'any' can't be used to index type

Casting the value or indexing doesn't seem to solve the issue. Is there no way to get around this error, or the only option I have is to use if/ switch statements.

Comment: Not enough info. Half the things in your snippets don't have definitions for us to use, so we don't know why you're getting this error either (and how to solve it). Can you give us how you defined the fields `input`, `output`, and whatever `this[this.formGroup]` is supposed to be?

Comment: What is `this.formGroup`?

Comment: so if the user sets a value of `123` in your `controlName`, you grab that value and match what exactly? if you do `this.formGroup.controls['controlName'].value`, that returns `123`, and you are looking at `this[123]`?

Comment: @Andres2142 not really, `controlName` is a dropdown so the user can only choose from a set of values, and those values are `input` and `output`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do the following:

```js
//somewhere in your project
export type MyType = 'input' | 'output';

@Component({...})
export class YourComponent {
  input = [...];
  output = [...];

  onSubmit(): void {
     const dropdownValue = this.formGroup.get('controlName')?.value; // it can be undefined
     const index: MyType = dropdownValue ? dropdownValue as MyType : 'input';
     
     this[index].push(...);
  }

}
```

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'any' can't be used to index type

Typescript complaints that the value you are getting is of type `any` and probably while trying to use it as an index, is wrong, for this, is recommended to use strong typing, such as creating a `type` where will match in this case with either of your class properties